# Filtering lists containing string pattern

Tags: list, filter, erlang

I need to filter elements in list containing string **Status=ACTIVE** and save it as new list.

Later I aslo need to filter same list with **Status=STOPPED** and **System=Windows**.

List:

```
Programs=
    ["Process=1,System=Linux,PID=240,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
    "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=240,Program=DRMX,Status=STOPPED",
    "Process=1,System=Windows,PID=240,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
    "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=242,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
    "Process=1,System=Windows,PID=242,Program=DRMX,Status=STOPPED",
    "Process=1,System=Windows,PID=242,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
    "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=246,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
    "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=246,Program=DRMX,Status=STOPPED",
    "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=246,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE"].
```

Wanted result:

```
["Process=1,System=Linux,PID=240,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
    "Process=1,System=Windows,PID=240,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
    "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=242,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
    "Process=1,System=Windows,PID=242,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
    "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=246,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
    "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=246,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE"].
```

and:

```
["Process=1,System=Windows,PID=242,Program=DRMX,Status=STOPPED"].
```

I found possible solution to filter it with re:run/2 and lists:filter/2. Is there a easier and faster way?

```
Filter=fun(Acc)->
    nomatch =/= re:run(Acc,"Status=ACTIVE") end.
Result=lists:filter(Filter,Programs).
```

Br,

Damian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one can be achieved by

```
lists:filter(
    fun (A) ->
        lists:member("Status=ACTIVE", string:tokens(A,","))
    end, Programs).
```

while the second one is a bit more complex, as it needs to verify two conditions:

```
lists:filter(
    fun(A) ->
        Tokens = string:tokens(A, ","),
        lists:member("Status=STOPPED", Tokens)
        andalso lists:member("System=Windows", Tokens)
    end, Programs).
```

I'm not sure it's faster, but it's at least much more readable.

Comment: `andalso` would be better than `and`. Though marginally with such short lists.

Comment: Thank you. This solution fits best in my program.

Answer (score 3):

Although [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52365225/49197) is perfectly correct I would write a little bit about Erlang best practices. One of very good practice is to transform data from outside of Erlang world as soon as possible to the proper Erlang structures. It will pay off in long-term project evolution and maintenance when a project will grow and become more complex, need proper operations, debugging, troubleshooting etc. So you usually would parse as much as possible of text data to the records, atoms, integers, numbers etc. It allows for two things. First, you verify incoming data as soon as possible and you will prevent the spread of errors inside of your system on a boundary. Which then allows use die fast approach. Second, you can write many helper functions which makes further development much easier. Something like

```
-module(programs).

-record(program, {
          process,
          system,
          pid,
          program,
          status
         }).

%% API

-export([parse_programs/1, active/1, stopped/1, linux/1, windows/1]).

parse_programs(L) ->
    [parse_program(X) || X <- L].

active(P) -> P#program.status =:= active.

stopped(P) -> P#program.status =:= stopped.

linux(P) -> P#program.system =:= 'Linux'.

windows(P) -> P#program.system =:= 'Windows'.

%% Internal functions

parse_program(Str) ->
    parse_program(string:tokens(Str, ","), #program{}).

parse_program([], P) -> P;
parse_program(["Process=" ++ Str | T], P) ->
    parse_program(T, P#program{process = list_to_integer(Str)});
parse_program(["System=" ++ Str | T], P) ->
    parse_program(T, P#program{system = parse_system(Str)});
parse_program(["PID=" ++ Str | T], P) ->
    parse_program(T, P#program{pid = list_to_integer(Str)});
parse_program(["Program=" ++ Str | T], P) ->
    parse_program(T, P#program{program = Str});
parse_program(["Status=" ++ Str | T], P) ->
    parse_program(T, P#program{status = parse_status(Str)});
parse_program([H | _], _) ->
    error(badarg, [H]).

parse_system("Linux") -> 'Linux';
parse_system("Windows") -> 'Windows';
parse_system(Str) -> error(badarg, [Str]).

parse_status("ACTIVE") -> active;
parse_status("STOPPED") -> stopped;
parse_status(Str) -> error(badarg, [Str]).
```

Then further tasks become easy

```
1> c(programs).
{ok,programs}
2> rr("programs.erl").
[program]
3> Programs=
3>     ["Process=1,System=Linux,PID=240,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
3>     "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=240,Program=DRMX,Status=STOPPED",
3>     "Process=1,System=Windows,PID=240,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
3>     "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=242,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
3>     "Process=1,System=Windows,PID=242,Program=DRMX,Status=STOPPED",
3>     "Process=1,System=Windows,PID=242,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
3>     "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=246,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
3>     "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=246,Program=DRMX,Status=STOPPED",
3>     "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=246,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE"].
["Process=1,System=Linux,PID=240,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
 "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=240,Program=DRMX,Status=STOPPED",
 "Process=1,System=Windows,PID=240,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
 "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=242,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
 "Process=1,System=Windows,PID=242,Program=DRMX,Status=STOPPED",
 "Process=1,System=Windows,PID=242,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
 "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=246,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE",
 "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=246,Program=DRMX,Status=STOPPED",
 "Process=1,System=Linux,PID=246,Program=DRMX,Status=ACTIVE"]
4> Ps = programs:parse_programs(Programs).
[#program{process = 1,system = 'Linux',pid = 240,
          program = "DRMX",status = active},
 #program{process = 1,system = 'Linux',pid = 240,
          program = "DRMX",status = stopped},
 #program{process = 1,system = 'Windows',pid = 240,
          program = "DRMX",status = active},
 #program{process = 1,system = 'Linux',pid = 242,
          program = "DRMX",status = active},
 #program{process = 1,system = 'Windows',pid = 242,
          program = "DRMX",status = stopped},
 #program{process = 1,system = 'Windows',pid = 242, 
          program = "DRMX",status = active},
 #program{process = 1,system = 'Linux',pid = 246,
          program = "DRMX",status = active},
 #program{process = 1,system = 'Linux',pid = 246,
          program = "DRMX",status = stopped},
 #program{process = 1,system = 'Linux',pid = 246,
          program = "DRMX",status = active}]
5> lists:filter(fun programs:active/1, Ps).
[#program{process = 1,system = 'Linux',pid = 240,
          program = "DRMX",status = active},
 #program{process = 1,system = 'Windows',pid = 240,
          program = "DRMX",status = active},
 #program{process = 1,system = 'Linux',pid = 242,
          program = "DRMX",status = active},
 #program{process = 1,system = 'Windows',pid = 242,
          program = "DRMX",status = active},
 #program{process = 1,system = 'Linux',pid = 246,
          program = "DRMX",status = active},
 #program{process = 1,system = 'Linux',pid = 246,
          program = "DRMX",status = active}]
6> lists:filter(fun(P) -> programs:stopped(P) andalso programs:windows(P) end, Ps).
[#program{process = 1,system = 'Windows',pid = 242,
          program = "DRMX",status = stopped}]
```

As a side effect, your program will consume much less memory because both numbers and atoms consume much less than strings. And any further processing will be much faster because all atoms comparison is just as number comparison and less memory mean more data in CPU cache and CPU cache hit is like two orders of magnitude faster than main memory access.

In this case

```
7> erts_debug:size(Programs).                                         
1062
8> erts_debug:size(Ps).      
153
```

It means you can stick almost seven times more data in your CPU cache. When you send messages between processes or nodes in Erlang distribution it will be seven times faster, ... (If you would use list_to_binary/1 for program name it would be even ten times difference.)

```
parse_program(["Program=" ++ Str | T], P) ->
    parse_program(T, P#program{program = list_to_binary(Str)});
```

then

```
9> c(programs).
{ok,programs}
10> f(Ps).
ok
11> Ps = programs:parse_programs(Programs).
[{program,1,'Linux',240,<<"DRMX">>,active},
 {program,1,'Linux',240,<<"DRMX">>,stopped},
 {program,1,'Windows',240,<<"DRMX">>,active},
 {program,1,'Linux',242,<<"DRMX">>,active},
 {program,1,'Windows',242,<<"DRMX">>,stopped},
 {program,1,'Windows',242,<<"DRMX">>,active},
 {program,1,'Linux',246,<<"DRMX">>,active},
 {program,1,'Linux',246,<<"DRMX">>,stopped},
 {program,1,'Linux',246,<<"DRMX">>,active}]
12> erts_debug:size(Ps).
108
```

So from 8.3KiB we are down to 864B.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly consider parsing such list to list of records to formalise the structure of the data. The filtering with the record becomes very elegant:

```
-record(program,{process,
                 system,
                 pid,
                 program,
                 status}).

% Parse list of strings to list of programs
ParsedPrograms=parseProgram(Programs),
[Valid || Valid = #program{status="STOPPED", system="Windows"} <- ParsedPrograms].
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string:str/2 or string:find/2 since str is obsolete.

```
ListA = [X || X <- Programs, string:str(X, "ACTIVE") > 0],
ListB = [X || X <- Programs, string:str(X, "STOPPED") > 0 and string:str(X, "Windows") > 0].

ListA = [X || X <- Programs, string:find(X, "ACTIVE") /= undefined],
ListB = [X || X <- Programs, string:find(X, "STOPPED") /= undefined and string:find(X, "Windows") /= undefined]
```